# Can I publish a Phonegap Android app to the marketplace?

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

So I built an app using JQuery mobile. I then used Phonegap to wrap it in
native Android code so I have user's download it as an app at the appstore.
However, the mobile app files are hosted on a server and may change from time to time.
Since the marketplace may approve the initial app, will they allow it to change once on the 
marketplace?

The content is dynamic, so will I be allowed to change it once its published?

Comment: There is no approval proces in the Android Market.

Comment: Hmm...I don't know why I thought that, thank Secator!

Answer (score 1):

Read this page: http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html for all information on publishing apps in Android Market. The page also explains about updating an app that's already in the Market.